# Area51: Linked comment in collider to deleted answer reports that "This proposal has been deleted."

Tags: bug, comments, area-51, stack-exchange-button

Comment links for answers that appear in the Collider for Area51 point to the wrong place.

**Example:**
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60750?noredirect=1, appeared in my collider, which produces the error message:

> This proposal has been deleted.

The answer (now deleted, so I don't have access to the comment permalink anymore) to which the comment is actually posted is http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60741/mobile-devices/60750.

Oddly enough, this worked until I deleted the answer.  Area51 apparently uses the same ID for questions and answers, but if the answer is deleted, the site cannot distinguish it from a proposal.