# Link to comment on deleted A51 question could look better

Tags: feature-request, area-51, deleted-questions

I recently (accidentally!) posted two identical questions on [an Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77834/rubiks-cube?referrer=1OBtgyh_32dQRnmhrB5egA2). When responding to a comment on the duplicated question (now deleted), I was surprised to see the error message that "This proposal has been deleted."

[The proposal has not been deleted](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77834/rubiks-cube?referrer=1OBtgyh_32dQRnmhrB5egA2), even though the question was.

[This is the link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79622) to the comment that is still in my notification box, so you can try it yourself.

Since the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [question has already been asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203329/266359) (h/t Shadow Wizard), I am requesting ( [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) ) for this to change, because it can be very confusing.

Here's a screenshot of the error that I got:
[image]